# How to handle strings containing HTML using Angular-Translate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to tell angular and [angular-translate](https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-translate/) to handle strings which contains HTML content.

I have `add_card-title = "To make ordering even quicker, <span class="nowrap">add a card now</span>"` as my Lang string. When i use it in my template by writing `<p>{{'add_card-title' | translate}}</p>` I get string as it is.

**Output:** `To make ordering even quicker, <span class="nowrap">add a card now</span>`
**expected output:** `To make ordering even quicker, add a card now`

I know i can use `ng-html-bind-unsafe` but it is not helping.

**Not working:**

```
<p ng-html-bind-unsafe="{{'add_card-title' | translate}}"></p>
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nTmMFm9B94BmbTgo2h8H?p=preview

For reference you can see this issue: https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-translate/issues/173

**note:** i do not want to invlove controller to handle it.

Comment: if the directive developers, who know their code , suggest using a directive...why wouldn't that work? Would actually take a lot out of your current markup, simplifying your templates creation

Comment: `ng-html-bind-unsafe` has been deprecated that's why it was not working.

Comment: @charlietfl can you point to the suggestion of the directive?

Answer (score 61):

You can do this out of box with [angular-translate 2.0](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive) these days.

```
<p translate="{{ 'PASSED_AS_INTERPOLATION' }}"></p>
```

works wonders for me.

Comment: You can simplify it: <p translate="PASSED_AS_INTERPOLATION"></p>

Comment: Can you advise how to make this work with interpolation-params? So the translate string might be `Maximum: <strong>{{value}}</strong>`.

Comment: @ChrisMoutray use the extra attribute `translate-values="{ value: 10}"`

Comment: Undocumented, but using an element works too, e.g. `<translate>TRANSLATE_KEY</translate>`

Comment: I'm trying to use this method and the closing span tag in the translation key is being added to the text as `<-span>`? ` `"backend_error": {
  "12004": "Invalid Login Credentials",
  "1111": "The email or password is incorrect. Did you <span class='underline'>forget your password</span>?"
 },` The translation key is output like this: `<span class="underline">forget your password<-span>?</span>' Any idea why?

Comment: I would need more context to the question.  My guess the browser is trying to autocomplete the span because of another html tag.  You can't have nested spans, so that is why I usually use div or p for this type of display.

Answer (score 22):

You have to use the ng-bind-html directive without curly braces ({{ }})

To know the configuration needed in order to use that directive (ngBindHtml), follow this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

After ngSanitize is included, the following code should work:

```
<p ng-bind-html="'add_card-title' | translate"></p>
```

Answer (score 17):

This works for me... the HTML is interpreted for nice styling (e.g. bold, italics, etc.)

```
<p translate="translationId"></p>
```

However, I also needed to ensure that I wasn't using escape strategy in the provider setup.  That messed me up for a while.

- **Works:** `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy( 'sanitize' );`
- **Nope:** `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy( 'escape' );`

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security

Using: angular-translate v2.13.1

Comment: `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy( 'sanitize' );` works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

You can use `<p [innerHTML]="'add_card-title' | translate"></p>`

Answer (score 7):

I have found the solution.
I was using `AngularJS v1.2.0-rc.3` which has got `ng-html-bind-unsafe` deprecated. Now angular has `ng-bind-html` instead of `ng-html-bind-unsafe`. But one has to inject [angular-sanitize](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-sanitize.js) as a dependency to get it working.

I replaced

```
<p ng-html-bind-unsafe="{{'add_card-title' | translate}}"></p>
```

with

```
<p ng-bind-html="'{{'add_card-title' | translate}}'"></p>
```

and things started working.

Comment: Where exactly do you inject angular-sanitize? And which tag? $sce?

Comment: @Sorcerer: You inject the `angular-sanitize` module when instantiating your application’s module as follows: `angular.module('myModule', ['ngSanitize']);`

Answer (score 2):

By default AngularJS escape and code it displays for safety reasons, you need to tell angular of the strings you don't want to escape, in older times before AngularJS 1.2 developers could do that by using `ng-bind-html-unsafe` but in AngularJS 1.2 that has been deprecated.

To use html tags in strings, in AngularJS 1.2+, you need to download `angular-sanitize` module and include it in your application dependencies.

Any string contains html code you can display it by using `ng-bind-html` Automatically uses $sanitize, in your case it will be `ng-bind-html="'add_card-title' | translate"`

For reference:

[On Medium](https://medium.com/@yabasha/how-to-use-ngsanitize-e4b35459ecb0#eb0e-33019fe608f4)

[AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

Answer (score 2):

Here are many ways to mix up html (along with scope variables, along with interpretion if you need things like ng-click in your html translations):

http://plnkr.co/edit/OnR9oA?p=preview

```
<div>{{'TESTING1_SIMPLE_VAR_REPLACE' | translate: '{name: "John Smith", username: "john.smith12"}'}}</div>
<div translate='TESTING1_SIMPLE_VAR_REPLACE' translate-values='{ name: "Jake Smith", username: "jake-smith-101"  }'></div> 
<div translate="TESTING1_SIMPLE_VAR_REPLACE_NA" translate-value-name="{{name}}" translate-value-username="{{username}}" translate-default="Hello {{name}} ({{username}})"></div>

<br/><br/>
<div>{{'TESTING1_SIMPLEHTML' | translate}}</div><!-- doesn't compile the html -->
<div translate="TESTING1_SIMPLEHTML" translate-default='DEFAULT(not used since there is a translation): This <b>translation</b> has a <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>.'></div><!-- this and below compile the html -->
<div translate="TESTING1_SIMPLEHTML_NA" translate-default="DEFAULT(used since translation not available): This <b>translation</b> has a <a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'>link</a>."></div>
Uses ng-bind-html and sanitize: <div ng-bind-html="'TESTING1_SIMPLEHTML' | translate"></div>


<br/><br/>
<div translate="TESTING2_SCOPE" translate-values="{timer: timer}" translate-default="DEFAULT(not used since there is a translation): Seconds: <a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'>{{timer}} seconds</a>."></div>
<div translate="TESTING2_SCOPE" translate-value-timer="{{timer}}"></div>
<div translate="TESTING2_SCOPE_NA" translate-default="DEFAULT(used since translation not available): Seconds: <a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'>{{timer}} seconds</a>."></div>

<br/><br/>
<div compile-unsafe="'TESTING3_COMPILE' | translate"></div><!-- old way to do before angular 2.0-->
<div translate="TESTING3_COMPILE" translate-compile></div>
<div translate="{{'TESTING3_COMPILE_SCOPE'}}" translate-compile translate-value-name="{{name}}" translate-value-username="{{username}}" ></div> <!-- not sure of advantage of this style, but saw an example of it -->
<div translate="TESTING3_COMPILE_SCOPE"       translate-compile translate-value-name="{{name}}" translate-value-username="{{username}}" ></div> 
<div translate="TESTING3_COMPILE_SCOPE"       translate-compile translate-values='{ name: "Jake Smith", username: "jake-smith-101"  }' ></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"lng_pageFooter" : "Copyright © • 2018 • My Company • Powered by <a href=\"http://www.mycompany.com\">My Company™</a>"
...
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');
....
app.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    return function(text) {
        div.innerHTML = text;
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(div.textContent);
    };
}])
....
<span ng-bind-html="'lng_pageFooter' | translate | trusted"></span>
```

Comment: Please explain what you did. Avoid only code answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @GSO, "Code-only" answers should not be deleted through the VLQ queue, as they attempt to answer the question. Instead, you should *encourage* the user to improve his answer.

Comment: Please, improve your answer by adding some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both your answers and none of them worked on 1.0.7 so for everyone that's working pre 1.2 you can do it like this

```
<p ng-html-bind-unsafe="'add_card_title' | translate"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use innerHtml. Eg `<p [innerHtml]="'lorem.ipsum' | translate"></p>`