# Adding <strong>/bold text in translated string using angular-translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, translation, angular-translate

I am currently look for a solution to put ONE bold word in a string being translated by the angular-translate filter. Sample code below: (I'm sure the solution is simple... I just can't seem to figure this one out!)

my language JSON file looks like so:

```
"AUTHENTICATE-ENTER-CODE": "blah blah blah"
```

In my html file I have this (which translates correctly according to key:value):

```
{{'AUTHENTICATE-ENTER-CODE' | translate}}
```

RESULT:
  "blah blah blah"

The result I am look for is "blah **blah** blah"

I could split this into multiple translation keys but the particular translation consists of multiple bold words in a few sentences... and I was told to attempt to keep the translations keys to a minimum since we have a couple hundred in this project.

I have tried putting the bold HTML tags surrounding the font I want to be bold (knowing it wouldn't work anyways) and no... it does not work! I also browsed through the angular-translate API and couldn't find exactly what I was looking for either.

Any input would be great!

Comment: `"AUTHENTICATE-ENTER-CODE": "blah <b>blah</b> blah"` doesn't work?

Comment: It doesnt if you use sanitization strategy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle strings containing HTML using Angular-Translate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754381/how-to-handle-strings-containing-html-using-angular-translate)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you using i18n or any other JSON file for content in Angular 2+ versions.Use this

> Json File

```
"TextWithHtmlExample": "blah <b>blah</b> blah"
```

> Html File (Angular Template)

```
<p [innerHTML]="'TextWithHtmlExample' | translate"></p>
```

> Output Will be-

blah **blah** blah

Comment: awesome solution

Answer (score -2):

**translate-compile**

Here is sample, I have tried to use html tags and as well as using directives in the translated string.

http://jsfiddle.net/walvekarnikhil/0j7pd40b/

```
<span translate="FOO" translate-compile></span>
```

Comment: `translate-compile` doesn't actually do this (and in fact it is set to true by default). The reason your jsfiddle works is because you don't set the sanitize strategy for `$translateProvider`, so angular-translate doesn't escape any HTML. This is also very unsafe and angular-translate warns you about this in the console.

Comment: @NeuroXc that's right, translate-compile is not solving the problem.