# How to handle inline html with angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

Lets say I want to have an icon inline in the text

```
'Please scan the <span class="icon ion-barcode"></span> on the screen'
```

How would i add that to a translation with angular-translate without splitting the sentence into two parts ?

```
'{{ 'scan_1' | translate }} 
 <span class="icon icon-barcode"></span> 
 {{ 'scan_2' | translate }}'

....

.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  var translations = {
    en : {
      scan_1 : 'Please scan the', 
      scan_2 : 'on the screen', 
    }
  };

  $translateProvider
    .translations('en', translations.en)
    .preferredLanguage('en');
}])
```

Comment: This is not a scenario supported by the translation service. Why not simply copy the entire text including the <span> elements and have a translation setup for it.

Comment: The translation is interpolated as text, not HTML. If you you put html tags in the translation they will be escapes resulting in `Please scan the <span class="icon ion-barcode"></span> on the screen`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle strings containing HTML using Angular-Translate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754381/how-to-handle-strings-containing-html-using-angular-translate)

Answer (score 1):

This might be possible with the `translate` *directive*:

```
<ANY translate="{{toBeInterpolated}}"></ANY>
```

Have a look [here](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754381/how-to-handle-strings-containing-html-using-angular-translate).